# Logic implies replacement

Tags: logic

An exercise in my book has the following facts

$A \lor B $

$C \Rightarrow B$

Then later the books says the above are equivalent to $A \lor C$

In another exercise I have the following facts

$A \lor B $

$B \Rightarrow C$

and again the book says the above are equivalent to 
$A \lor C$

My intuition says that cannot be true in both cases, since if that were true $B \Leftrightarrow C$

Did the book made a typo or I get something wrong?

Comment: For the first one, they are not equiv. With $A$ and $C$ FALSE and $B$ TRUE, we have that $A \lor B$ and $C \to B$ are both TRUE while $A \lor C$ is FALSE.

Comment: For the second, we have that from $A \lor B$ and $B \to C$ we may derive $A \lor C$. See [Resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#A_simple_example).

Answer (score 1):

You're right, that makes no sense.

In fact, neither of those two are equivalent.

To be exact:  the conjunction of $A \lor B$ and $C \rightarrow B$ is not equivalent to $A \lor C$, and neither is the conjunction of $A \lor B$ and $B \rightarrow C$.

It *is* true that $A \lor B$ and $B \rightarrow C$ together *imply* $A \lor C$.

But $A \lor B$ and $C \rightarrow B$ do not not together imply $A \lor C$.

We can see all this using a truth-table:

\begin{array}{ccc|c|c|c}
A&B&C&(A \lor B) \land (C \rightarrow B) & (A \lor B) \land (B \rightarrow C) & A \lor C\\
\hline
T&T&T&T&T&T\\
T&T&F&T&F&T\\
T&F&T&F&T&T\\
T&F&F&T&T&T\\
F&T&T&T&T&T\\
F&T&F&T&F&F\\
F&F&T&F&F&T\\
F&F&F&F&F&F\\
\end{array}

Rows $3$, $6$, and $7$ show that $(A \lor B) \land (C \rightarrow B)$ is not equivalent to $A \lor C$, and in fact row $6$ shows that $(A \lor B) \land (C \rightarrow B)$ does not even imply $A \lor C$

Rows $2$ and $7$ show that $(A \lor B) \land (B \rightarrow C)$ is not equivalent to $A \lor C$, but we do see that whenever $(A \lor B) \land (B \rightarrow C)$ is true, $A \lor C$ is true as well, and hence $(A \lor B) \land (B \rightarrow C)$ does imply $A \lor C$